# How does docker recognize if run -v option refers to host directory or a docker volume?

Tags: docker, syntax, docker-command

When executing `docker run` with option `-v a:b`, `a` could refer either to a directory on the host, or a docker volume name. How does docker recognize which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does docker recognize which one is it?

If `a` contains a `/` slash, it is a directory. Otherwise, it is a volume name.

Comment: Does it imply the path needs to be absolute?

Comment: It does not imply that. The `-v` parameter has to be absolute anyway. But for example `docker compose` takes relative paths.

Comment: As of Docker 23, you can use relative paths on `docker run` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#volume

Comment: @HansKilian ah, but relative path still must start with `./` in order to indicate it is a path?

Comment: `order to indicate it is a path?` yes